# How to install templates from nuget package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-templates

I know I can install nuget packages from templates:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/visual-studio-templates

But I'd like to do the opposite, I'd like to install templates - provided by the nuget package - after the package was installed.

I read I could create a powershell script and run that after the package's been installed. Is that the only way? What are my options here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core it can be done using

```
dotnet new --install <id of your template package>
```

See [docs for the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21)

Comment: It doesnt show up after installing. what could be the reason? I tried running as admin as well. It does show/list the templates after that command but i dont see the new template that i try to install.

Comment: Well, for what its worth, after various attempts, it finally worked - by closing all the VS instances, running the admin mode of VS Developer Shell (again).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, found that:

1. Dotnet 5.0 can't load templates from my nuget server by id, but dotnet 6.0 can, and puts .nupkg file to %USERPROFILE%.templateengine\packages
2. VS 2022 and new Rider view these templates.
3. Dotnet 5.0 can install template by .nupkg local path, and puts it to %USERPROFILE%.templateengine\dotnetcli\v5.0.404\packages
4. After step 3 you can use templates in Visual Studio 2019, but I also have ide.host.json in .template.config folder
   https://github.com/sayedihashimi/template-sample#supporting-visual-studio-2019